# Should The Header Containing The Title of a Form Be In The Form Group or Outside It?

Tags: html, forms

Let's look at the following simple form,

```
<form>
    <h3>
        Edit Client
    </h3>
    <label>
        Name
        <input type="text">
    </label>

    <label>
        Occupation
        <input type="text">
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Is it correct, as above, to put the `H3` tag in the Form Group? It seems either way, because

- It is not a form element, and so does not belong in the form group
- It is a description of the form, and so belongs in the group

Is there an official style guide that can be referred to here?

Comment: [From this it seems possible.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html) As `Legend`.

Answer (score 1):

The [WHATWG specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element) of the HTML *form* element states:

> Content model: Flow content, but with no form element descendants.

So the *form* element may contain flow content, which is defined as

> Most elements that are used in the body of documents and applications

This means there are not a lot of restrictions which HTML elements you can put inside a *form* element. Heading elements (e.g. *h3*) are flow content, thus explicitly allowed.

So there is nothing wrong with writing your HTML code like you do, using an *h3* element for describing a part of the form.